# persist a user id from redux state after page refreshes

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a simple React app that displays a list of chat groups that a user creates through a get request by using the user_id that is stored in redux state.  The component does fetch the groups correctly on the initial render but when I refresh the page the page, the user_id is undefined resulting in not fetching the data. I've looked into persisting to local storage but I'm thinking there is a better option? I'm new and just trying to figure out the best option.

```
const Groups = props => {
const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);
    const { user_id } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`/api/groups/${user_id}`)
            .then(res => setGroups(res.data))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
            })
    }, [user_id]);


    console.log('groups', groups)
    return (
        <section>
            <Heading2 text='Groups' />
        {groups.map(group=><p>{group.name}</p>)}
        </section>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = reduxState => {
    return {
        user_id: reduxState.userReducer.user.user_id
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Groups);
```

Comment: try [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist)

Comment: What happens if someone just goes directly to this page by the URL?  You can use local storage (which is what redux-persist uses behind the scenes in a typical web installation), but you also need to deal with redirecting traffic to a login page when there is no `user_id` to be found.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `redux-persist` to achieve the persistence against page refreshes. You should have already configured the `store` from `redux`. Just follow the given example below.

Change your createStore function as below

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web


import rootReducer from './reducers'
 
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}
 
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
 
export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```

And change your root component as below

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
 
// ... normal setup, create store and persistor, import components etc.
 
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootComponent />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

You should be able to see the persisted `user_id` in redux dev tools and in the local storage in the `Application` tab in the browser dev tools after a refresh.

You can whitelist only the reducers you want instead of persisting whole `store`. Check the npm package page for more details => https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Answer (score 2):

You need to use whitelist to persist values from redux store.

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: "root",
    storage: storage,
    whitelist: ['user']
};
```

Check out the below link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist